# Collision detection and response with a square-square animation

Tags: javascript, animation

Hey, I'm working on a mini 2D-animation in Javascript where you a moving cube and when you hit one of the edges of the view window, it should bounce off and continue moving(for example: a cube moving diagonally down, hits the bottom side of the view, then bounces up diagonally). 2 things I having a bit of trouble with is a) getting the damn cube to move, which I sure I would need to setInterval or something of the sort and b)The collision detection and response for the moving cube, which I figured you need to check the 4 sides of the cube and if they hit any of the sides, move accordingly. Any helpful hints and tutorials anyone can point me to would be appreciated. Thanks!!

UPDATE: Have the cube moving now just working on the collisions. My first attempt didnt work though it sounds correct in the mind. Any corrections are of course welcomed:

```
   if(x/left position of box > (width of window view - width of box)){

     go left

    } else if(x/left box pos < (width of window view + width of box)){

        go right

    } else if(y/top box pos > (height of view - height of box)){

        go down

    } else if(y/top box pos < (height of view + height of box)){

        go up

    } else {

        box.style.left = parseInt(box.style.left) + 2 + 'px';
        box.style.top = parseInt(box.style.top) + 5 + 'px';

    }
```

Comment: I am not. From all the demos with ball-cube animations I googled, I didn't see <canvas> used

Answer (score 0):

- create two or more object;
- get the x,y while moving (plus dimension)
- find if x,y matches of any other object; if yes its collied already
- [jQuery collision detection during animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182100/jquery-collision-detection-during-animation)