# Translate element by constant amount with CSS for smoother animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, animation

Is it possible to translate an element by a constant amount with CSS? For instance, we want to move a `div` in 50 pixel increments up the screen. Right now, we use update the translate value manually, but this creates a choppy effect.

Here's the code, where `translate` equals a value that increments by 50 every time this line is called:

```
$(element).css( '-webkit-transform', 'translate3d( 0, ' + translate + 'px, 0)' );
```

We need this work on mobile devices so we can't use jQuery `animate` because it is not smooth enough (in our experience) on mobile. We need to translate by a constant amount because we need to track the element's position so we call the translate code every X ms.

Comment: Are you looking for http://api.jquery.com/animate/?

Comment: Have you tried? How did that work out?

Comment: Why not just set the `animation-timing-function` and `animation-duration` properties appropriately?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, that is our code that we tried. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @robertc We need to keep track of our position so we call the translate line every X ms.

Comment: `element.style.webkitTransform='translate3d( 0, ' + translate + 'px, 0)'` inside a `setinterval` loop?

Comment: Right, I'm asking why?  What else do you need to do apart from the translating?

Comment: @Deadpool Yes, that's what we're doing now, but it's too choppy.

Comment: @robertc We need to keep track of the element's position. That's the only reason we do it this way. Is there a better way to animate an element while tracking its position? Thanks!

Comment: OK, let me try asking the same question in a different way: What are you doing with the element's position information that isn't related to the animation itself?

Comment: Why do you need to track the element's position? What are you doing with that number?

Comment: @robertc Gotcha. We use the element's position to track collisions with another element. So the root problem is how to animate elements while detecting collisions.

Comment: @kmoe We use the element's position to track collisions with another element. So the root problem is how to animate elements while detecting collisions.

Comment: @Crashalot ah, gotcha. There are a couple of questions on SO about that problem - have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837167/jquery-animate-collision-detection ?

Comment: OK, then instead of constantly firing off repeated animations I'd just set one animation with appropriate values, then [detect the current position](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8920934/8655) in your loop rather than trying to do the animation in it.

Comment: @robertc Hmmm, thanks. We read elsewhere on SO that you couldn't retrieve the position since translation isn't actually affecting the element's positioning in the flow.

Comment: @robertc Never mind. We actually tried this, and it works. The other SO posts must have been wrong. Could you post this as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: [This seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/sJaMV/76/), when animating CSS properties

Comment: @robertc Yup we tested ourselves and found that the other SO posts must have been wrong. Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constantly firing off repeated animations I'd just set one animation with appropriate values, then [detect the current position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8920934/8655) in your loop rather than trying to do the animation in it.  [This updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/sJaMV/76/) from the linked question seems to indicate it would work.

You may want to interrogate the [`transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to get the current translation values if they're going to be more complex than simple top/left.  You should get a value that looks something like this:

```
matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 300)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several jQuery plugins that extend the animate method to use CSS3 and make animations very smooth on mobile devices.

I've used in the past a couple of plugins, don't remember the ones I used, but a quick Google search gave me this one:

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

It would be something like this:

```
$(element).transition({ y: '+=50' });
```