# How do I implement collision detection between a set of Div elements?

Tags: jquery, collision-detection

I have this example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/dzEs4/1/)

I have a var as being the collision element:

```
var $div = $('.container');
```

and then the collision:

```
function test (){
    $('.drag')
        .drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
            dd.limit = $div.offset();
            dd.limit.bottom = dd.limit.top + $div.outerHeight()
                - $( this ).outerHeight();
            dd.limit.right = dd.limit.left + $div.outerWidth()
                - $( this ).outerWidth();
        })
        .drag(function( ev, dd ){
            $( this ).css({
                top: Math.min( dd.limit.bottom, Math.max( dd.limit.top, dd.offsetY ) ),
                left: Math.min( dd.limit.right, Math.max( dd.limit.left, dd.offsetX ) )
            });   
        });
}
```

for:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="drag xxx" style="left:40px;"></div>
<div class="drag xxx" style="left:120px;"></div>
<div class="drag xxx" style="left:200px;"></div>
```

This code implements collision detection of the child divs against the container div.  How would I implement collision detection to make those 3 divs collide with each other?

I'm thinking to set up another div : `var $divs = $('.xxx');` but im not sure how to use it within this example.

Comment: By "collide with themselves," do you mean "prevent over/underlap?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please recommend a JQuery plugin that handles collision detection for draggable elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773717/please-recommend-a-jquery-plugin-that-handles-collision-detection-for-draggable)

Comment: w can see that they collide with  the `<div class="container"></div>` container i also want to collide with them self

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Full [collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) and correct [collision response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_response) isn't a trivial problem to solve, except in special cases.

The code you have now is fairly easy to write because you only have two objects to compare (the dragged object and the container), and because your collision response was simply to restrict the div's position to be inside the container.

For full collision against all the divs, you'll have to check the dragged div against the container and all other divs.  Your collision response will have to calculate a movement vector, and handle complex "sliding" logic to make sure you can move around other objects, but ensure that your final position will still be inside the container.

I'd suggest you first reexamine your need for full collision detection, as it can be perf-heavy and complicated.  Maybe you just need [**overlap detection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-testing), ala jQuery UI's [`droppable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)?  Or maybe you need something like jQuery UI's [`draggable` snapping](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to), or jQuery UI's [`sortable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)?

If you determine you actually need full collision detection, I suggest you grab a library that already handles collision detection since it is hard to implement.  See answers on this question for a few library options:

- [Please recommend a JQuery plugin that handles collision detection for draggable elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773717/please-recommend-a-jquery-plugin-that-handles-collision-detection-for-draggable)

If you really want to implement it yourself, you should look up the Separating Axis Theorem:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separating_axis_theorem

I'd then read the articles on implementing collision detection and response as seen in [the `N` game](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/):

- http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html
- http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialB.html

If you need to search for more info, you can consider divs to be [`Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume) (`AABB`s).  This can give you huge perf increases and huge complexity reductions.  The math for checking `AABB`-to-`AABB` collision is about as easy as it gets for overlap and collision detection (though collision response is still as hard as with any other type of collision).