# Element touching another element JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I see if an element is touching another in JavaScript? I am a beginner so I was looking for something simple that doesn't require a lot of coding.

Comment: This should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916874/can-you-tell-if-one-element-is-touching-another-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) which will give you a bounding box including `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, …. If it's rectangular elements, then you can simply check if they intersect.

Comment: But how can i use Element.getBoundingClientRect() to see if 2 divs (1 of them is draggable) is touching the other one. Im just a begginer so idk how to use js that well.

Comment: @LirikRexhepi Using math. You have `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties available as well.