# If element is over another element?

Tags: jquery

With jQuery how do i find out if div `one` is over div `two`?  Not, which z-index is higher but what div is visually over the other div.

```
<style type='text/css'>
    #one {
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red; z-index:2;
    }
    #two {
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:green; z-index:1;
    }
    </style>    
    <div id='one'></div>
        <div id='two'></div>
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628368/how-do-i-implement-collision-detection-between-a-set-of-div-elements

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `offset` method ([here](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)) to get the space from the document edges. Add the width and height of the elements, and substract the numbers.

[image: Offset and width for div's]