# Detect if element touches another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a little game with jQuery. The game involves moving elements. I need to check while the element is moving if it touches another element. The only way I can think of to do this is by checking every step of the animation (I'm using animate method in jQuery) the position of the elements. It's really hard way to this because in my game there are a lot of moving objects. There is another way to do that?

Comment: see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607252/how-to-detect-when-an-element-over-another-element-in-javascript

Comment: There isn't a universal function which would solve your problem, please post some code and let us see what we can do...